# dateFormatter returns an NSDate of nil in Sweden

Tags: macos, datetime, cocoa, nsdate

I'm having an odd problem with converting a datetime that is in the UTC timezone when this code is run in Sweden.

```
NSString* utcDateTime = @"5/23/2017 4:34 AM";
NSString* localTimeNSString = [self convertUTCDateTimeToLocal:utcDateTime];
NSLog(@"localTime:%@", localTimeNSString);
```

Inside my conversion function, my attempt to parse this datetime into an NSDate returns nil:

```
- (NSString*)convertUTCDateTimeToLocal:(NSString*)theUTCDateTime
{
    NSString* localTime = nil;

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    if (dateFormatter) {
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

        // parse the passed parameter, theUTCDateTime, which looks like this: "05/23/2017 04:34 AM"
        // Even though this date / time doesn't LOOK like a UTC-formatted timestamp, it is in the UTC timezone

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
        NSDate* utcTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:theUTCDateTime];

        // in Sweden, dateFormatter will return utcTime as nil.  Not so in the United States or England.
        // In the US, NSLog of utcTime is "2017-05-23 04:34:00 +0000"

        // Now that we've parsed into an NSDate, display date & time the way the user's system is configured
        // Of course, if utcTime is nil, then so is localTime (below)
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        localTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:utcTime];

        // in the US, dateFormatter will return localTime as "5/22/17, 9:34 PM"
    }

    return localTime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry -- force of habit (the codebase it is part of is Objective-C++, but I get that the question is not a C++ language question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` uses the current locale. Set the locale of the formatter to a US locale if you want to recognize dates in a US format.